# Why do I get compile errors in every project, even new ones, and how do I fix them?

Tags: unity

I downloaded the latest version of Unity as you can see in the snap.

[image: console after creating new project]

I just created a new project and when I press the play button it shows compile error even if I have not created anything nor any script. I receive 4 blank errors in Unity and one non critical. I am not able to clear them except the non critical one.

Comment: researched in fourms but no success at all

Comment: Looks like it's another bug in Unity. You can switch to an older version as a workaround

Comment: which version should i downgrade sir

Comment: For me, 2018.2.7 works, but maybe any of 2018.3.x will work for you

Comment: do 18.27 work for you or should i download the 4 or 5 one

Comment: is 2018.2.7 work pefectly

Comment: error still exist in 2018 3.0 version i am just crying now

Comment: try another versions that's all I can advice

Comment: I know this is an old question… Yet, I find these blank errors amusing. Hopefully you have found a newer version that works by now, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by importing packages by unity. You can found **Package** inside **project inspector**.

[image]

this may be a little different for your project but solution to this is really simple, 
Open up package manager from **Windows->Package manager**. And remove the **"unity** **collaborate"** package if it didn't resolved the problem then remove the **"Text mesh** **pro"**. this sort of problem is usually caused by these two packages. If the problem is not yet resolved them remove all the packages except **"Package Manager UI"**. this resolve all the errors. **If you need any of the package then you have to reinstall it.**

[image]

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound simple, but have you restarted Unity? It could also be a package import issue. Especially with an empty project, try opening the Package Manager and reset to defaults.

Comment: i did everything restarted ,reset defaults in the unity hub but o succes now i am downloading unity 2018 3.0

Comment: i that works i will tell hre

Comment: where i found the reset to defaults option?